# Full disk - /dev/mapper

Tags: disk-usage

After erasing some log files I have got enough space to reboot (I am still to reboot, I want to figure out first what is happening).

After some prints, sizes do not explain the problem:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg01-root   39G   27G   11G  73% /
udev                   990M  4.0K  990M   1% /dev
tmpfs                  200M  812K  199M   1% /run
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   999M   12K  999M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1              228M   27M  189M  13% /boot
```

/dev/mapper using 27 GB.

Let's see files with more than 50 MB:

```
$ sudo find / -type f -size +50M -exec du -h {} \; | sort -n
find: `/proc/10412/task/10412/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/10412/task/10412/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/10412/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/10412/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
0       /proc/kcore
0       /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.0/resource0
51M     /var/www/vhosts/somewhere
67M     /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
86M     /var/log/syslog.1
158M    /var/log/mail.log
364M    /opt/psa/var/log/maillog-backup
```

Nothing really worrying, is it? Does anyone understand the first four lines error?

Let's see a summary of folders' size at /

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 -x /
4.0K    /lib64
9.5M    /home
86M     /root
0       /dev
9.1M    /etc
808M    /opt
1.0K    /boot
12K     /media
8.6M    /sbin
0       /proc
0       /sys
1.4G    /var
4.0K    /selinux
20K     /tmp
214M    /lib
16K     /lost+found
0       /run
4.0K    /mnt
2.0G    /usr
8.7M    /bin
4.0K    /srv
4.5G    /
```

I still do not know where the 27 GB used by /dev/mapper are.

Any suggestion?

If I reboot, will all turn into normality again?

Thank you!

Comment: After rebooting, /dev/mapper comes back to normality, with below 5 GB of disk usage. Does anyone know why? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the files that you deleted were still open by a running program, and so could not be freed yet.  Rebooting killed that program and freed the space.

Comment: thank you for your comments. Yes, I guessed so. However, having a look at the last command display, /proc is not using memory, and the /proc/swaps is placed there. Do you know why it was not showing there the 27 GB? Thank you!

Comment: @rellampec, /proc is a virtual filesystem that provides information about the running system.  Nothing in there is actually on a disk.

Comment: psusi: thank you! I have no one clue how to avoid the same problem in the future. The files were mainly log files of mail, during an infection in Joomla sending spam.

Comment: @rellampec, assuming these logs are managed by syslog, you can send it a  SIGHUP to close and re-open its log files and that will free the log files you just deleted immediately.